# Why the apparent lack of IMAX 3D releases for Justice League?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, distribution, 3d, imax, justice-league

I was looking at showtimes for the movie *Justice League* and was only able to find it in three formats: regular 2D, IMAX 2D, and RealD 3D.  I couldn't seem to find any IMAX 3D showtimes, either in my area or anywhere else.

So my question is, has *Justice League* been released in IMAX 3D at all? If not, I wonder why, because it seems that IMAX 3D is superior to RealD 3D and the 3D footage seems to exist.

Comment: Related meta discussion: [Are questions about the use of specific technologies in the cinema industry on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4049/49)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been released in IMAX 3D outside of the US, but not in the US. This is easy to see on the official IMAX site: https://www.imax.com/movies/justice-league

In Europe all IMAX screenings are 3D, in the US all IMAX screenings are 2D.

Sites like bowtiecinema.com even took down their original IMAX 3D listings for Justice League (http://www.bowtiecinemas.com/movies/justice-league-an-imax-3d-experience/).

The reason is that

> You might start seeing a drop in 3D IMAX releases very soon.
>
> After seeing its stock drop three cents per share in the second quarter of 2017, IMAX CEO Greg Foster said in a conference call that the company would be "looking forward to playing fewer 3D versions of films and more 2D versions.”
>
> [...]
>
> But this announcement is one of the first indications we've seen that audiences might not enjoy the 3D experience as much as the industry would have us believe. The experience requires that moviegoers wear cheap glasses that dim the picture—all for a higher cost than a ticket for a standard, 2D movie.

Source: http://televisions.reviewed.com/news/is-3d-finally-dead-imax-may-move-away-from-3d-in-the-us

Comment: This could also be due to the technology in use by IMAX for 3D. It is an outdated, linear-polarized technology, and I have no idea why they don't switch to circular polarizers (the difference is, if you move your head in IMAX, 3D effect gets very weird). It also has the tendency to make people sick/give them headaches regardless of polarization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been released in [IMAX 3-D](https://www.imax.com/movies/justice-league).

I am pretty sure that you can go to websites like [bookmyshow](https://in.bookmyshow.com/buytickets/justice-league-3d-bengaluru/movie-bang-ET00050968-MT/20171120) and check the movie timings by clicking at the English-3D and switching it to IMAX-3D.

Comment: That's an Indian site.  Do you know if it's been released in IMAX 3D in the US?

Comment: Yes, I do. Please check the first link as well.

Comment: The first link is only displaying showtimes in IMAX 2D, not IMAX 3D.

Comment: Oh, let me check. Can you let me know your location please.

Comment: I live in New Jersey.  But I can't seem to find IMAX 3D showtimes for Justice League anywhere in the US.

Comment: Apparently, you are right. Give me some time to look into it. Also, it worth the watch in IMAX 3-D :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68973/discussion-between-abcdexter-and-keshav-srinivasan).